# Different results for the same code with different Ifc versions

Tags: c#, ifc, xbim

When I run the code below to get ifcWindow Area quantity using Ifc4 file and Xbim.Ifc4 interfaces it works perfectly.

[image: code]

But, When I'm trying to run on the same schema as Ifc2x3 file and using Xbim.Ifc2x3 interfaces it doesn't recognize RelatingPropertyDefinition property and performs the following error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZoSn.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IFC 2x3 schema implementation in xbim Toolkit implements IFC4 interfaces to keep the code backwards compatible and to be able to write one code base for both schemas. But IFC4 doesn't implement IFC2x3 interfaces. `RelatingPropertyDefinition` is new in IFC4, so you would have to restructure the code. But bare i mind, that if you use IFC2x3 interfaces, it will **only** work for IFC2x3 files. If you use IFC4 interfaces, it will work for both schema versions. In fact, we plan that in the future there will always only be one set of interfaces to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks!, But when trying to work with IFC2x3 files and IFC4 interface many of the elements are null, What do you mean by restructure the code in order to get the win area for example?

Comment: You will need to be a lot more specific. Which elements are null?

Comment: for example: when exporting IfcDoor from model they were NULL. Anyway I managed to get the win area in another way. Thank you